# how to pre select elements on a ListSelectionDialog in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, dialog

is it possible in a ListSelectionDialog in eclipse to pre select some of the entries?
and if so, how do I select them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `setInitialSelections` with an array containing the objects you want to select. This must be done before calling `open`.